# List of objects. Operations with Integer entries

Tags: java, list, object, autoboxing

The List might contain both Integers and String values. In this case, should I create the List of Objects, right?

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

How to perform simple arithmetic operations with the Integer entries of the List?

```
list.add(1);
list.add("ok");
list.add(2);
Integer a = list.get(0) - list.get(2); // does not work
```

Comment: Why can't you have 2 lists: one for ints, the other for Strings?

Comment: I like your thinking, it seems so natural to try this. Goes straight to my list of what's wrong with auto boxing in Java.

Comment: @Victor Sorokin: It would be a good solution, if I had only String and Integer. In reality, there might be more types. Therefore I need to keep high level of generics in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the `Object`s to int, because the `-` Operator isn't defined on `Object`s and Java does not unbox these automatically.

```
Integer a = ((Integer)list.get(0)) - ((Integer)list.get(2));
```

Comment: Hey, it appears that I did a downvote on your post instead of an upvote. Could you do a small edit so that I can undo this?

Comment: @Milad Naseri I appreciate your honesty :-) There you go. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Sorry for the trouble. I was just being careless :)

Answer (score 5):

That's because ultimately, `list.get(0);` is an `Object`. You have to cast it if you want to do arithmetic operations on it:

```
Integer a = (Integer) list.get(0) - (Integer) list.get(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad design to be honest. What if you want to iterate over that list? You will have to manually check if the element is a string or an integer. Generics where introduced to Java for a reason.

Can't you make 2 lists: one for strings and one for integers. Or at least use one list but instead of using strings use a (normally unused) integer value?

Comment: No.unfortunately I cannot do this. I´m reading the data from DB, and for some specific reasons I need to keep these data in a single List.

Comment: I understand there might be some specifics we are not aware of. Still I would encourage you to at least try and refactor this piece of system. Otherwise it will be a time bomb which will only increase the technical debt with each day.